# How to write Users checkbox checks into multiple records in database - using MVC, C#, Razor, nHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, nhibernate

So im trying to insert into my database the values from check boxes that the user checked.

In my ViewModel:

```
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserTitlelist { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Titles { get; set; }
```

In my View:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Titles)
  {
    <label class="managelabel" style="padding: 0 5px 0 5px;"><input name="Title" type="checkbox" value="@item.Value" @checkedcheckbox> @item.Text</label>
  }
```

In my Controller:

```
 var titleToInsert = new UserTitle
  {
   UserId = currentUserId,
   TitleId = model.Title[];
   };
  UserManagerService.UpdateUserTitles(titleToInsert);
```

In UserManagerService:

```
public static int UpdateUserTitles(UserTitle userTitle)
    {

        using (ITransaction transaction = Context.BeginTransaction())
        {
            foreach (var x in userTitle)
            {
                Context.Save(userTitle);
            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You view model is incorrect and has no relationship at all to what you are editing. And `SelectListItem` is a class for use in `@Html.DropDownListFor()`, not for a collection of checkboxes.

You view models should be

```
public class TitleVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class UserTitleVM
{
  .... // other properties
  public List<TitleVM> Titles { get; set; }
}
```

And in the view

```
@model UserTitleVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Titles.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Titles[i].ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m =>m.Titles[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Titles[i].IsSelected, Model.Titles[i].Name)
  }
```

and in the controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(UserTitleVM model)
{
  // Get the ID's of the selected titles
  List<int> selectedTitles = model.Titles.Where(t => t.IsSelected).Select(t => t.ID);
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer is quite simple:

in the controller:

```
var myList = Request.Form["Title"];
            foreach (var item in myList.Split(','))
            {
                var titleToInsert = new UserTitle
                {
                    UserId = currentUserId,
                    TitleId = Convert.ToInt32(item)
                };
                UserManagerService.UpdateUserTitles(titleToInsert);                
            }
```

then in UserManagerService:

```
public static int UpdateUserTitles(UserTitle userTitle)
    {

        using (ITransaction transaction = Context.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Context.Save(userTitle);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This way each record gets saved individually

Comment: Sorry, but this must be one of the most anti MVC solutions I have seen